# Обработка математич. выражения в форме строки для применения к интервалу(python)

Tags: python, парсер

Мне нужно обрабатывать математические выражения, которые содержат стандартный набор операторов (+,-,/), все возможные математич. функции (cos, sin, взятие по модулю и т.п). Эти мат. выражения должны обрабатываться в форме строки(преобразовываться из строки в мат.выражение) и я бы смог применить их на определенном интервале как если бы я написал функцию, к примеру: sin(x)*cos(x) в коде и смог бы применить к этому интервалу. Как это сделать, хотелось бы, чтобы вы привели пример, если существует какая-либо библиотека для этой задачи.

Comment: То есть, вы искали что- то, но не нашли?

Comment: Да, я искал, но не нашел примера для решения моего вопроса

Comment: вы плохо искали https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval (для начала)

Comment: Ну куда уж мне до Вас))

Comment: @strawdog ast.literal_eval умеет разбирать только литералы, но не вычисляемые выражения. Тут нужен eval или numexpr.